# Using scanf_s to determine array length

Tags: c

I need help with creating a 1-dimensional array using the length that the user entered it. I need to use a scanf_s as this is part of the assignment. I know this is something to do with pointers but I'm still new and unfamiliar on how to use them. Thanks for the help!

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int N;
    printf("%s", "Please enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    int array[N];
}
```

I'm getting an error at `int array[N];`

Comment: If this is Microsoft compiler, it does not support VLA (variable length array) and you must dynamically allocate the memory with a function such as `malloc()`. That is where your pointer will be obtained.

Comment: "*I'm getting an error*". Please edit the question to show the exact error. You may also consider searching for that error on Stack Overflow or in your favourite search engine.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to clarify. Yes, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a static array with a malleable value. This will not work on certain compilers. I recommend using `malloc()`:

```c
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int N;
    printf("%s", "Please enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    int* array = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    /* Your code */
    free(array);
}
```

One catch about `malloc()` is that you need to call `free()` to give the memory you allocated, back to the system. Therefore, I added a comment (`/* Your code */`) to indicate where the code using `array` should go, and added `free(array);` to free the memory that was allocated.

Comment: Hmm... Weird I am getting an error underneath `malloc`. It says: a value of type "void" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int *"

Comment: @MrGriefer I updated my answer, try adding `(int *)` before the malloc. Malloc returns a type of `void*` so casting it to `int*` should work.

Comment: @MrGriefer Note that the cast from `void *` is ***not*** required in standard-conforming C.  Make sure you're not compiling as C++ instead of C. See [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: MrGriefer, PQCraft, In C, Better as `int* array = malloc(sizeof *array * N);`